# How do I use rules in webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

In [this Angular starter project](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js) we see...

```
module: {
  rules: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

so I try to follow suit and change

```
module: {
  loaders:[
    ...
  ]
}
```

To the one above, however, now it fails to transpile Typescript using the ts-loader. If I change it back to loaders it works great.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rules` was added for webpack2 only. It depends what version of webpack you are using. The starter repo [uses](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/package.json#L127) webpack2.

Comment: I was wondering about that I am using webpack 1.x if I do npm install -g webpack2 will it upgrade?

Comment: You should be able to do `npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.25`